# whats wrong with the android code ?

Tags: java, android

whats wrong with the android code ? I want this code to give Incorrect when the

entered answer is wrong and correct when the answer is correct but every time 
  get is incorrect

and are my  casting variables correct

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView Jlabel1;
    TextView Jlabel2;
    TextView Jlabel3;
    EditText Jtextbox1;
    Button b1;
    int m;
    int ans;
    String ans1;
    String k;

    @Override


        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Jlabel1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Jlabel2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Jlabel3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Jtextbox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        double q = Math.random();
        double w = Math.random();
        int e = (int) (q * 10);

        int z = (int) (w * 10);
        ans = e + z;

        Jlabel1.setText(Integer.toString(e));
        Jlabel2.setText(Integer.toString(z));

        ans1 = String.valueOf(ans);


        k = Jtextbox1.getText().toString();


        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ans1.equals(k)) {
                    Jlabel3.setText("Correct");
                } else {
                    Jlabel3.setText("Incorrect");
                }

            }
        });
    } 
}'
```

Comment: Try to debug ans1 and k values before if loop. See what is the values?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see what's going on? Stack Overflow isn't a debugging service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a copy of the contents of the edittext too early. Move the

```
k = Jtextbox1.getText().toString();
```

inside the `onClick()`.